# Finding average of exponential

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ a$ be a nonzero real number. Then how to evaluate the following limit for each nonzero $a$,
$$ \lim _{ N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=-N}^{N} e^{2 \pi i a n /N}?$$

Using geometric sum, I am getting the answer is $0$. Could someone please tell me whether I am correct or not. If not, how to proceed. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a sequence of Riemann sums (with partition
$$
-1, -1+1/N, \dots , 1-1/N, 1
$$
of the interval $[-1,1]$).

As $N \to \infty$
$$
\sum_{n=-N}^N \exp(2 \pi i a \frac{n}{N})\frac{1}{N} 
=\exp(2 \pi i a )\frac{1}{N}+\sum_{n=-N}^{N-1} \exp(2 \pi i a \frac{n}{N})\frac{1}{N}  
$$
$$
\to 0+ \int_{-1}^1\exp(2 \pi i a t) dt = \frac{1}{2 \pi i a}(\exp(2\pi i a)- \exp(-2\pi i a))
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2 \pi i a}2i\sin(2\pi a) = \frac{1}{\pi a}\sin(2\pi a).
$$